# Redefining enum for public/private interface

Tags: c++

How can I use the members of `enum state_t` in the method `bar::install` without redefining it in the public class section of `foo`? Class member `_state` must stay `protected`.

Is it a good idea just to use another enum with similiar names for the members?

```
class foo
{
protected:
    int         _bla
    volatile enum state_t { _REC, _LIN, _OFF } _state;
public
    volatile enum { REC, LIN, OFF };
    state_t get_state(void) { return _state };
};
```

Within a method of another class:

```
void bar::install(foo *ptr)
{
    switch(ptr->get_state()) {
        case foo::REC: break;
        case foo::LIN: break;
        case foo::OFF: break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, when you duplicate your enums you suffer extra effort when you modify them, you will also run into errors/warnings related to theirs types. I would make `state_t` public and keep `_state` protected by separating their definition, like this:

```
class foo
{   
public:
    enum state_t { REC, LIN, OFF };
protected:
    int         _bla
    volatile state_t _state;
public:
    state_t get_state(void) { return _state };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `bar` as friend class of `foo`